# Как правильно задать условие JS - Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется:

```
function hide(c_id) {
 if($(".item > .b-item_"+c_id).parent() == hide()){ // проверяем скрыт ли родительский элемент
 $(".item > .b-item_"+c_id).parent().show(); // если скрыт, то при событии onclick показываем обратно
 }else{ //в противном случае
 $(".item > .b-item_"+c_id).parent().hide(); // скрываем родительский элемент (блок div)
 }}
```

Условие не функционирует корретно, получается только скрыть родительский элемент если просто указать:

```
function hide(c_id) { $(".item > .b-item_"+c_id).parent().hide();}
```

Необходимо чтобы при нажатии на событие onclick="hide('this.id')" происходил скрытие элемента - если элемент не скрыт, если элемент скрыт - то показать

Comment: есть такой метод `toggle`. Пользуётесь)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hide(c_id) {
if ($(".item > .b-item_" + c_id).parent()[0].hidden) { 
 $(".item > .b-item_" + c_id).parent().show();
 } else { 
 $(".item > .b-item_" + c_id).parent().hide();
}}
```